# Group by one column and select more than one column Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group by more than one columns but in special case:

I have a table of `(Payment_Type,Year,TotalMoney)`

I need to get sum of total grouping by `payment_type(cash or credit)` only and I need to select year in my query how can I do it? my query is:

```
select Payment_Type,Year,SUM(TotalMoney) 
from table 
where 1=1 
group by Payment_Type,Year
```

I get an error message as:

> Year is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: are you using `ODBC` for function call?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear, I don't see anything wrong with your current syntax.  Can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

```
select Payment_Type,Year(YourDateColumn),SUM(TotalMoney) 
from table 
group by Payment_Type,Year(YourDateColumn)
```

if your column is named year then

```
select Payment_Type,[Year],SUM(TotalMoney) 
from table 
group by Payment_Type,[Year]
```